# Write text to tkinter text widget redo

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, undo-redo

I have a tkinter text widget, and I added the undo/redo features using these code:

```python3
self.text = tk.Text(self, maxundo=-1, autoseparators=1, undo=True)
```

I then inserted some strings into it:

```python3
self.text.insert('insert', 'Text')
```

I pressed <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> and <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>,
I found out that I can only undo or redo text inserted by keyboard presses, not `text.insert`ed text.
So, I want to know how to make the text widget undo the text inserted using the `insert` method.
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add an edit separator before and after inserting your string.

```
self.text.edit_separator()
self.text.insert('insert', 'Text')
self.text.edit_separator()
```

The edit separators let tkinter know what the logical chunks of the text are. Adding the separators tells tkinter that your insert command should be treated as a single unit as far as undo is concerned.